# the position of the max and min of a YCBCR frame in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I was if there any function in OpenCV, that call tell me  the X and Y position of the max or the mean value of my  Ycbcr frame  . I've already done  the conversion from RGB and I can find the max and the min but that with for loop that take me just too much memory

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`minMaxLoc`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#minMaxLoc) function should help you to do that.

**Update:** For example:

```
Mat src = imread("image.jpg"), tmp;
cvtColor(src, tmp, CV_BGR2YCrCb);

//extract Y
extractChannel(tmp, tmp, 0);

Point min, max;
double minV, maxV;
minMaxLoc(tmp, &minV, &maxV, &min, &max);

cout << "Max value is " << maxV << " at position " << max << endl
     << "Min value is " << minV << " at position " << min << endl;
```

The output:

```
Max value is 255 at position [52, 19]
Min value is 0 at position [28, 1]
```

Comment: thanks Astor for your answer but, the minMax function deliver the max and Min location, of one vector, I don't know how it can possible to extract the Y values and putting them in one vector without using loops

Comment: what are you talking about? one vector - what is it??? It returns position (point) to the min or (and) max.  `Point* minLoc=0, Point* maxLoc=0`

Comment: let's say, I have YCBCR  frame, it has 3 channel Y , Cb and one for C,  so if I extract the Y channel (I don't know how it could be done) if  Y will be its self a matrix, for minmaxloc I need to convert it to a vector so I get the max and min position on the the vector but not of my YCbcr Matrix. I hope that I made it clear :)